# How can i implement time driven tasks in C on win32 platforms?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, timer

I'm new to C and trying to find some code snippets to figure out how time triggered tasks can be implemented in C. I have two functions whose execution times may vary from 50 to 200 ms. I want to pass these functions to a worker thread which should be scheduled to run every 500 ms. Is there in C (win32-platform) a simple way (like java's TimerTask) to implement timer tasks with standard run time libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Using c you can use the win32 [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Function

Answer (score 1):

Use `CreateTimerQueueTimer` to have windows call your function every 500ms:

```
void CALLBACK timer_function(void* /*lpParameter*/,BOOLEAN /*TimerOrWaitFired*/)
{
    /* do stuff */
}


HANDLE timer_handle;

void start_timer()
{
    void* parameter; /* passed as lpParameter of timer_function */
    DWORD milliseconds_before_first_call=100; /* execute after 100ms */
    DWORD milliseconds_between_calls=500; /* and then every 500ms */
    CreateTimerQueueTimer(&timer_handle,NULL,timer_function,parameter,
        milliseconds_before_first_call,milliseconds_between_calls,
        WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION /* the function takes a while, and may block */
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `TimerQueue` related functions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682483(v=vs.85).aspx